# Static verb vs participle

Tags: verbs

> A crowd of people had gathered to watch the youth take his final breath and throw stones at him.

Why is that sentence using *take* and not *taking*?

Comment: Similar to:     *http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/is-i-watched-them-go-grammatically-correct*    and to:     *http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/i-saw-him-crossing-vs-i-saw-him-cross*    Much guidance on this question at: *http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive*

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *static* (the context suggests you mean *finite*), but *take* is an infinitive.

Comment: I'm assuming *static* here means non-*continuous*. Some posters have referred to the "taking" version as *continuous*, which I'm assuming means "continues on through time*.  If the event is only a single point in time then *it* will not be changing, even if it itself represents a change in something.

Answer (score 1):

"**I watched the sun go down.**" means I watched the whole event (go down) from beginning to end (whatever that means in the context of the sentence), whereas "**I watched the sun going down.**" means I watched the sun at some point while it was in the act of going down (maybe the whole event, but maybe only a glimpse at any point in the process).